# Calling Excel Solver from another sub is giving different results than manually

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I need to run Solver in a sheet ("Sheet1") for different values of a parameter called "air", this parameter is not part of the parameters of Solver, but it has an impact on the results, so i create a table in "Sheet2" with differents values of "air" and made a code to run Solver for each "air" value to "recover" some results from Sheet1 and put them in the same table in "Sheet2"

This is the code i made for "Sheet2"

```
Sub F1()
    Dim air() As Variant
    air = Selection.Value 'Selection of different % of "air" from a table in Sheet2
    i = UBound(air, 1) 'Length of air array
    For j = 1 To i
    Sheet1.Range("$H$35").Value = air(j, 1) 'Change parameter "air" of Sheet1
    Call Sheet1.Resolver 'Run Solver on Sheet1 to obtain new results
    ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, 1).Value = Sheet1.Range("$P$132").Value 'Paste new result "$P$132" from Sheet1 on a cell one space right to "air" in table from Sheet2
    ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, 2).Value = Sheet1.Range("$A$54").Value 'Paste new result "$A$54" from Sheet1 on a cell two spaces right to "air" in table from Sheet2
    ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, 3).Value = Sheet1.Range("$P$117").Value 'Paste new result "$P$117" from Sheet1 on a cell three spaces right to "air" in table from Sheet2
    Next j  
End Sub
```

And this is the sub Resolver from Sheet1:

```
Sub Resolver()
  SolverReset
  SolverOk SetCell:=Range("$A$51"), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0",   ByChange:=Range("$H$36:$H$38,$A$54"), Engine:=1
  SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$A$45"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=0
  SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$A$47"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=0
  SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$A$49"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=0
  SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=False
  SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
  SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
End Sub
```

This code is working but i am getting wrong values if i compare them with results obtained manually running the sub Resolver. For example:

Using the first code:

```
air      x       y         z
0,10    56,52   35,08     7.093,49
0,20    56,52   35,08     5.716,48
0,30    56,52   35,08     4.787,19
0,35    56,52   35,08     4.427,32
```

Using the second code manually:

```
 air    x      y       z
0,10  74,29   57,79   9.324,50
0,20  67,19   48,13   6.796,69
0,30  60,08   39,43   5.089,14
0,35  56,52   35,08   4.427,32
```

On the results from the first code only the last row is ok, because before running F1 i run Resolver manually with a value 0,35 of "air". If i change the order of "air" values they are the same, only 0.35 row is ok.

Then i realized that in "Sheet2" after running F1 the values of cells $A$51, $H$36:$H$38, $A$54, $A$45, $A$47, $A$49 (the same used in Resolver) are 0, so now i think that the problem is that Resolver is running on "Sheet2" instead of "Sheet1". So i tried the following:

```
Sub Resolver()
  SolverReset
  SolverOk SetCell:=Sheet1.Range("$A$51"), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:=Sheet1.Range("$H$36:$H$38,$A$54"), Engine:=1
  SolverAdd CellRef:=Sheet1.Range("$A$45"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=0
  SolverAdd CellRef:=Sheet1.Range("$A$47"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=0
  SolverAdd CellRef:=Sheet1.Range("$A$49"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=0
  SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=False
  SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
  SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
End Sub
```

But is not working, how can i run "Resolver" in "Sheet1"? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting that only the last one is correct. Change the order of the elements of 'air' and run it so see if the last one is correct and 0.35 is not. If so, then run the F1 sub step-by-step with the F8 key and see if it changes the values you want. The Resolve code is fine but probably only the SolverSolve line is needed (do you really need to Reset each time?).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, I change the order or air element and realized that the row 0,35 is ok because before run F1 I run Resolver manually with a value 0,35 of air. I realized too that the Resolver is running on "Sheet2" instead of "Sheet1".
I use SolverReset because if not the constraints begin to repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I don't know if it's dirty code or not, but is working.

Adding the following code on F1:

```
Sheet1.Select
```

Before calling Resolver.

And

```
Sheet2.Select
```

To go back to Sheet2 and "paste" the data.

Then:

```
Sub F1()
On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim air() As Variant
air = Selection.Value 'Selection of different % of "air" from a table in Sheet2
i = UBound(air, 1) 'Length of air array

For j = 1 To i
Sheet1.Range("$H$35").Value = air(j, 1) 'Change parameter "air" of Sheet1
Sheet1.Select
Call Sheet1.Resolver 'Run solver on Sheet1 to obtain new results
Sheet2.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, 1).Value = Sheet1.Range("$P$132").Value 'Paste new results "$P$132" from Sheet1 on a cell 1 space right to "air" in table from Sheet2
ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, 2).Value = Sheet1.Range("$A$54").Value 'Paste new results "$A$54" from Sheet1 on a cell 2 spaces right to "air" in table from Sheet2
ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, 3).Value = Sheet1.Range("$P$117").Value 'Paste new results "$P$117" from Sheet1 on a cell 3 spaces right to "air" in table from Sheet2
Next j

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
errHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With

```
Sub F1()
On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
....(code)...
....(code)...
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
errHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End sub
```

To avoid flickering between sheet changes.